# How to configure window dialogue behaviour on multiple displays

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have 3 displays connected to DELL PRECISION M4800 laptop (build-in laptop display and two monitors - BENQ G2420HD).

```
1 - laptop display | 2 - first monitor (main display) | 3 - second monitor
```

I am facing some inconveniences when working on display 2 and 3, for example, when I am working with chrome opened on 3rd display it opens confirmation dialogs on 1st display, same with some confirmations dialogs in TortoiseSVN.

Is it somehow configurable in windows where to open dialogs or it just usability bugs if apps that I am using? I noticed that some windows remember their position when you drag them on other screen but with dialogs that does not work for me.

Comment: You can go to Screen resolution and specify the screen that you want to use at the time. Disable all others and check, should work fine.

Comment: I want to use all screens at the time - this is why I connected those.